# Optimizing a multiple output function in R using optim, preferably with gradient

Tags: r, optimization

I recently switched to R from matlab and I want to run an optimization scenario.

In matlab I was able to:

```
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);
[theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);
```

Here is the equivalent of costFunctionReg (here I call it logisticRegressionCost)

```
logisticRegressionCost <- function(theta, X, y) {
    J = 0;
    theta = as.matrix(theta);
    X = as.matrix(X);
    y = as.matrix(y);   

    rows = dim(theta)[2];
    cols = dim(theta)[1];
    grad = matrix(0, rows, cols);

    predicted = sigmoid(X %*% theta);
    J = (-y) * log(predicted) - (1 - y) * log(1 - predicted);

    J = sum(J) / dim(y)[1];

    grad = t(predicted - y);
    grad = grad %*% X;
    grad = grad / dim(y)[1];

    return(list(J = J, grad = t(grad)));    
}
```

However when I try to run an optimization on it like:

```
o = optim(theta <- matrix(0, dim(X)[2]), fn = logisticRegressionCost, X = X, y = y, method="Nelder-Mead")
```

I get an error due of the list return. (When I just only return J it works)

Error:

> (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Q1: Is there a way to specify which return should the optim use for the minimization? (like fn$J)

Q2: Is there a solution where I can use the gradient I calculate in the logisticRegressionCost?

Comment: I've used `optim` to fit a perceptron some time ago. My function just accepted `w` and returned the error value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do this because the documentation for `optim` says `fn` should return a scalar result.

Perhaps you could just write a helper function to optimize. Something like:

```
logisticRegressionCost.helper <- function(theta, X, y) {
   logisticRegressionCost(theta, X, y)$J
}
```

Also, you don't need the semi colons to suppress output in R. I had that same habit when I switched from MatLab too :)